# xjc with annox running from command prompt

Tags: binding, jaxb, annotations, xjc, annox

I have tried to run a example from the website http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin#AnnotatePlugin-Activation. The very first schema provided in the webpage and I saved it as schema.xsd under c:\jaxb folder. Then, I ran the command 'xjc -extension schema.xsd' from command prompt and I get the similar error. Apparently xjc doesn't seem to understand this url http://annox.dev.java.net. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

- You have to add the annotate plugin with all the dependencies to the classpath. See this [Ant build file](https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/samples/annotate/project-build.xml) for what dependencies are
- You have to activate the plugin using `-Xannotate` switch

Here's a [sample Ant project](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22jaxb2-basics-sample-annotate%22). I'll assemble a command-line example for the next version.

Comment: Sorry, all ok, it was me.